# How to find the sum of $k$th powers of all proper divisors of first $n$ numbers

Tags: number-theory, divisor-sum

I am trying this problem but unable to come up with efficient algorithm can someone help with this problem.
I have solved the easier version of the problem 
below is the problem link.

Thanks in advance

[Spoj 14175. Power Factor Sum Sum (hard)](http://www.spoj.com/problems/AFSK/)

Comment: See [Divisor function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function).

Comment: Thanks for replying, but I need to find the sum of all divisor form 1 to n.

Comment: Could you provide an example for lets say n=4?

Comment: Sure suppose we have to find the sum of all proper divisors up to 4 and power is 1 SOD 4[1,2,4] so sum of k ths power should be let k=1, [1^1+2^1+4^1]=7 3[1,3] SOD [1^1+3^1]=4 2 [1,2] SOD 2[1^1,2^1] =3 1=1 so sum of divisor of Kth power from 1 to 4 is 7+4+3+1=15 that is is the desired result

Comment: Yop can have a look at my python solution I have used the same algo to solve the easier version http://ideone.com/B69hC0

Comment: You can see from the comments of the SPOJ page that this is meant to be very challenging.  The algorithm must be efficient, but it's likely you'll need to also optimize implementation details that are outside the scope of this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding up tp r9m answer:
The original problem asks you for the sum of all divisors, counting $n$ as a divisor of $n$.
An interesting thing to note here is that
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\left\lfloor\frac{n}{i}\right\rfloor i^k=\sum_{i=1}^x \sum_{j=1}^{\lfloor n/i\rfloor} j^k-x\sum_{j=1}^{\lfloor n/x\rfloor}j^k+\sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor n/x \rfloor} \left\lfloor\frac{n}{i}\right\rfloor i^k\tag1$$.

This can be generalized and proved graphically as follows:
For any $f$, and $x,n\in \mathbb N$ such that $0<x\le n$
$$\color{#96A}{\sum_{i=1}^n\left\lfloor\frac{n}{i}\right\rfloor f(i)}=\color{#5A5}{\sum_{i=1}^x \sum_{j=1}^{\lfloor n/i\rfloor}f(j)}-\color{#B55}{x\sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor n/x\rfloor}f(i)}+\color{#68A}{\sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor n/x\rfloor} \left\lfloor\frac{n}{i}\right\rfloor f(i)} \tag2$$.

[image: Result]
[image: Suma1]
[image: Suma2]
[image: Suma3]
**Note:** There is actually no problem if $x$ is not in one of the *steps* of the *stair*, the proof still works.

---

But, why would we do such thing? Well, if you set $x=\lfloor \sqrt n\rfloor$, since we can compute 
$$\sum_{i=1}^{x}i^k$$
in *constant*(assuming contant time basic arithmetic) time using [Faulhaber's polynomials](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PowerSum.html), we have effectively reduced the number of operations necessary to compute $(1)$ to $O(\sqrt n)$. Alas, we need to have previous knowledge of the bound of the bound of $k$, so that we can hard-code the necessary polynomials(but luckily, the bound given in the problem is $1\le k\le10$ which are exactly the polynomials that you can find in the link).

Answer (score 1):

Note that $2$ is a proper factor of half the numbers less $1$, so if the upper limit is $n$ it will contribute $(\lfloor \frac n2 \rfloor -1) 2^k$ to the sum.  This avoids factoring any of the numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Simply count the number of times $m$ appears in the list of all the divisors of $\{1,2,...,n\}$, it is $[\frac{n}{m}]$, (where, $[a]$ is the floor of $a$). So the sum of $k$-th power of proper divisors is $\sum\limits_{m=2}^n m^k([\frac{n}{m}]-1)$.

Comment: As the OP is asking for _proper_ divisors only, $\sum_{m={\mathbf 2}}^n m^k\left(\left\lfloor\frac{n}{m}\right\rfloor-1\right)$ would be more appropriate.

Comment: edied .. thanks :) @barto

Comment: Although the SPOJ problem is not asking for this.